# How to rewrite specific URL using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been breaking my head on this for quite some time and I don't see the solution.

I want to rewrite a URL with a GET language parameter to a more clean URL.

For instance:

- `http://www.example.com?lang=en`

Needs to be:

- `http://www.example.com/en`

The above works fine with this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|nl|fr|de)/?$ /?lang=$1 [L]
```

But I can't get it to work on URLs like these:

- `http://www.example.com/contact.php?lang=en`
- `http://www.example.com/about.php?lang=en`

That need to be:

- `http://www.example.com/en/contact.php`
- `http://www.example.com/en/about.php`

Anyone have an idea what I'm missing in my rewrite rule to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need an additional rewrite rule for handling `/en/about.php`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(en|nl|fr|de)/([\w-]+\.php)$ $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(en|nl|fr|de)/?$ /?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thx, can you breakdown the first rewrite rule and  explain what it does ? It does indeed return te correct page using the clean URL, but the server can't find my script and css files, because it now looks in /nl/scripts/jquery.js instead of /scripts/jquery.js. Tia !

Comment: First rule, matches & captures one of the languages in `$1`. Additionally it captures `about.php` in `$2` using `[\w-]+\.php` expression after `/`. In target we use `$2?lang=$1` to forward this to `about.php?lang=en`

Comment: To fix css/js issue you need to add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Great ! That's it. Works like a charm ! Thx a lot !